# How can I apply Noether's theorem to translation symmetry?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, string-theory, noethers-theorem

I want to calculate the Noether's current for translation symmetry of the Polyakov action in conformal gauge. The action reads:

\begin{align}
S = \int d^2\sigma(\eta^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha x^\mu\partial_\beta x^\nu\eta_{\mu\nu})
\end{align}

which is of course invariant under translation $x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu+c^\mu$.

How can I calculate the conserved current from this transformation? Since I don’t know how to construct an infinitesimal transformation from this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Noether trick (see e.g. page 19 of [David Tong's QFT notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf)). Make $c^\mu$ depend on the worldsheet coordinates, $c^\mu(\sigma)$, and take the variation of the action with respect to that transformation. The change in the action will be
$$\delta S = \int\mathrm{d}^2\sigma\ (\partial_\alpha c^\mu) J_\mu^\alpha.$$
$J^\alpha_\mu$ will be your current, since you can show that $\partial_\alpha J_\mu^\alpha = 0$, by an integration by parts.