# Conserved charges of the classical string

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, string-theory, noethers-theorem

In classical mechanics we can get conserved currents from symmetries via the action principle. The action of a classical theory may be of the form:
\begin{align}
S = \int d\tau L(x^\mu,\dot{x}^\mu)
\end{align}
Therefore we have can derive the Euler-Lagrange equations as well as a conserved charge
\begin{align}
\partial_\tau\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}^\mu}\delta x^\mu-K\right)=0
\end{align}

In string theory however a string follows a worldsheet instead of a worldline, therefore we need two parameters $\tau, \sigma$ and the action may be of the form

\begin{align}
S = \int d\tau d\sigma L(x^\mu,\dot{x}^\mu,x'^\mu)
\end{align}

This changes the equation for the conserved charge to
\begin{align}
\partial_\tau\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}^\mu}\delta x^\mu-K^\tau\right) + \partial_\sigma\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'^{\mu}}\delta x^\mu-K^\sigma\right) = 0.
\end{align}

I have a few questions about this

1. can we conclude that both terms in the equation above vanish independently? In this case $\tau$ is the timelike coordinate of the worldsheet so if we speak of conserved charges we mean that it is conserved in time. So only the first term should be of interest.
2. If both terms vanish independently does the first one give us a charge that is conserved in time and the second one a charge that is conserved along the string?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/764720/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for a conserved current is
$$\partial_\alpha\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\alpha x^\mu)}\delta x^\mu - K^\alpha\right) = 0,\tag{1}$$
where $\alpha\in\left\{\sigma,\tau\right\}$ is a worldsheet index, and importantly *you are summing over them*. This means, you cannot take them to vanish independently. Writing (1) out in $\tau$ and sigma you get (accounting for the signature of the worldsheet):
$$-\partial_\tau\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^\mu}\delta x^\mu - K^\tau\right) + \partial_\sigma\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial {x'}^\mu}\delta x^\mu - K^\sigma\right)= 0.$$

Note also, that (1) is exactly the same as the usual conservation of currents in a quantum field theory, whereby
$$\partial_\alpha\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\alpha \phi^i)}\delta \phi^i - K^\alpha\right) = 0,$$
where now $\alpha$ is a base-space index (whatever that may be) and $i$ is an internal index of the fields. There you simply have that $\partial_\alpha J^\alpha = 0$, and you cannot take each summand to be zero independently.

To obtain the conserved charge, from (1), you compute
$$Q = \int_\gamma \mathrm{d}\sigma J^\tau,$$
where $\gamma$ is either a segment or a circle depending on whether the string is open or closed. You can see that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \int_\gamma \mathrm{d}\sigma\ \partial_\tau J^\tau = \int_\gamma \mathrm{d}\sigma\ \partial_\sigma J^\sigma = J^\sigma(\partial \gamma) = 0.$$
The latter is zero because $\partial\gamma=0$ in the case of the closed string, or because of suitable boundary conditions in the case of the open string. So you see you still get a conserved charge.

Comment: I had a copy paste mistake which I corrected. So your equation is the same as what I got . So we can not assume both terms to vanish independent. But then this equation does not give me a conserved charge. It describes the relation between the changes of two quantitys.

Comment: @Aralian I updated my answer.